# С помощью каких библиотек можно на Python 3.8 работать с кликами мыши?

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек

Хочу сделать программу, которая при нажатии на ЛКМ будет производить не 1 клик, а 2.

Answer (score 2):

https://pypi.org/project/pynput/

По описанию должна подойти читает кликает логирует

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам подойдёт [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

**pyautogui**

Документация: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

А вот как сделать 2 клика:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.doubleClick()
```

Подробнее в документации